# Why isn't this allowed before super()

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I have been coding in React js. I have read that in ES6 classes to access 'this' we need to first call super(props) and I would like to know why this is.Answers I have found mainly talk about Javascript being unable to know what 'this' is unless superclass is called. I would like to know what that means because outside the constructor, 'this' is recognized and we don't call super(props) each time.

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { /* initial state */ };
  }
}
```

Comment: I think, and anyone correct me if I am wrong, that until super() is called, the instance is not created which means, this won't be pointing to anything until then

Comment: I have seen code where 'this.{property}' is used before super({properties}) . Is it that in such cases the properties of the parent are used?

Comment: You must call super()

Comment: @U.P , you asked to be corrected if you were wrong — well, you are :) When you instantiate a class, the first thing to happen is the prototype of the class being instantiated to be cloned, this clone being the new instance. Only after the instance already exists, yet in an uninitialized state, every constructor in the prototype chain is called upon that instance sequentially, from the `Object` constructor towards the one you called using the `new` operator.

Comment: @U.P , The `super` constructor to be called before everything else is required to ensure that once the execution reaches the rest of the code in the subclass constructor, the instance is fully initialized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The constructor method is a special method for creating and initializing an object created with a class. There can only be one special method with the name "constructor" in a class. A SyntaxError will be thrown if the class contains more than one occurrence of a constructor method. A constructor can use the super keyword to call the constructor of a parent class.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

It means if you have `class MyComponent extends React.Component` you always need `super()` call in order to make this defined.

> If you don't specify a constructor method, a default constructor is used.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor#Default_constructors

Constructor of superclass should be called before `this` in order to finish configuration of `this` before subclass started configuration of `this`. Otherwise superclass constructor could get `this` modified by subclass. Superclass should not know something about subclasses. That is why `super()` call in constructor should be before access to `this`.

Comment: I feel like these two citations don't answer the questions at all, and your comment just repeats the fact without explaining it.

Comment: Well. Let me add few words then. Constructor of superclass should be called first in order to finish configuration of `this` before subclass started configuration of `this`. Otherwise superclass constructor could get `this` modified by subclass. Superclass should not know something about subclasses. Thats why `super()` call in constructor should be before access to `this`.

Comment: Why the call to "super()" is not implicit when you don't write it? there is a good reason for that?

Comment: @Alex, the subclass's constructor might take different parameters than the superclass constructor. And then making `super()` explicit only when the constructor takes no args would be inconsistent (and also hard to detect - eg what if it uses `arguments`). Honestly tho I think ES6 is ruining javascript and the no-this-before-super is one of the many reasons.

Answer (score 22):

This is really complicated, unfortunately.

---

The short story: **access of `this` in a subclass before `super()` call is not allowed, because in ES6 `this` is being born in the base class**, therefore `super()` is needed to initialize it.

For more information, refer to [15.6.2 Allocating and initializing instances](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html#_right-column-the-prototype-chain-of-the-instance)<sup>1</sup>. The author is one of the few people that explains this in detail.

Here is a relevant sample from the book<sup>1</sup> above.

> Under the hood, it roughly looks as follows.

```
// Base class: this is where the instance is allocated
function Person(name) {
    // Performed before entering this constructor:
    this = Object.create(new.target.prototype);

    this.name = name;
}
···

function Employee(name, title) {
    // Performed before entering this constructor:
    this = uninitialized;

    this = Reflect.construct(Person, [name], new.target); // (A)
        // super(name);

    this.title = title;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Constructor function will return 'this' by default. According to oops concept child class always inherit 'this' object from parent class by super() call. so if we try to use this in child class without super call it will throw an error.
If we return anything except 'this' from child class then super() call is not necessary.
I have explained by some simple examples.

example 1

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 0;
  }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}
const instanceA = new A();
console.log(instanceA) // A {a: 0}
const instanceB = new B();
console.log(instanceB) // Error: Must call super constructor in derived class before 
accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor
```

example 2

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 0;
  }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
      return {b: 3}
    }
}
const instanceA = new A();
console.log(instanceA) // A {a: 0}
const instanceB = new B();
console.log(instanceB) // Object {b: 3}
```

example 3

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 0;
  }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
      super()
    }
}

const instanceB = new B();
console.log(instanceB) // B {a: 0}
```