# FAB not working in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, floating-action-button

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, View, Button, Icon, Fab } from 'native-base';
export default class FABExample extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      active: 'true'
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (  
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Fab
            active={this.state.active}
            direction="up"
            containerStyle={{ }}
            style={{ backgroundColor: '#5067FF' }}
            position="bottomRight"
            onPress={() => this.setState({ active: !this.state.active })}>
            <Icon name="share" />
            <Button style={{ backgroundColor: '#34A34F' }}>
              <Icon name="logo-whatsapp" />
            </Button>
            <Button style={{ backgroundColor: '#3B5998' }}>
              <Icon name="logo-facebook" />
            </Button>
            <Button disabled style={{ backgroundColor: '#DD5144' }}>
              <Icon name="mail" />
            </Button>
          </Fab>
        </View>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

I am using the above code in order to add a FAB in my project. But I'm getting an error:

> Body:{"type":"TransformError","snippet":" 3| constructor() {
>           4| this.state ......

Comment: add `super();` before `this.state {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an error in the sample code given by the NativeBase. In order to correct error add **super();** in your constructor like below.

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    active: 'true'
  };
}
```

You can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539654/why-isnt-this-allowed-before-super) for more details why contructor need to call super before accessing '**this**'

Comment: Thank you.. now the error is gone. but the sub icons are displaying by default.

Comment: Can you please tell what is meant by sub icons? If you are referring the facebook, whatsapp share icons, I can see that code written in the snippet you have shared. Could you please clarify ?