# Call method from parent class inside child class

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I've recently started to learn about `Classes` in `javascript` and while reading some really interesting stuff I thought of trying some of my own ideas.

If you have a parent class of `Parent` in which you have a `method` of ````` logSomething```` and a child class of `````Child`, with which you do`class Child extends Parent`, how can you then execute the inherited method from the parent class,`logSomething```, inside of the child class?

If you define a method inside of the `Child` class and add `this.logSomething()` to that method, whenever the method from the child class is called, the inherited `logSomething` function will indeed run, but apart from that I haven't found any way of executing the `logSomething` directly inside of that child class.

I've tried `this.logSomething()`, I've tried adding it to a object, self executing (IIFE) function and everything I could thing of but to no result.

```
class Parent {
  constructor() {}

  logSomething() {
    console.log('I am logging something')
  }

}

class Child extends Paren {
  logSomething() // This does not work
}
```

Currently doing this does not work, if throws a error referring to the fact that it things your trying to define a function.

I know it should be possible in some way, if I'm not mistaking `React` uses something similar with `life-cycle methods` right? Such as `componentWillMount`.

How would one go about doing this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43591507/673457

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First error is that you are extending `Paren` instead of `Parent`.
Also you cannot just throw a random statement inside in a class. It needs to be inside a function.
If you want it to run whenever you create an instance of that class it should be inside the `constructor` or a function that gets called by it. (note that you need to call `super()` at the start of the constructor. 
Finally, you still need to use `this.logSomething` or `this.logSomething`

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {}

  logSomething() {
    console.log('I am logging something');
  }

}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.logSomething(); // Will use Parent#logSomething since Child doesn't contain logSomething
    super.logSomething(); // Will use Parent#logSomething
  }
}

new Child();
```

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {}

  logSomething() {
    console.log('Parent Logging Called');
  }

}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.logSomething(); // Will call Child#logSomething
    super.logSomething(); // Will call Parent#logSomething
  }

  logSomething() {
    console.log('Child Logging Called');
  }
}

new Child();
```

You could also do this:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {}

  logSomething() {
    console.log('Parent Logging Called');
  }

}

class Child extends Parent {
  logSomething() {
    console.log('Child Logging Called and ...');
    // Careful not use this.logSomething, unless if you are planning on making a recursive function
    super.logSomething();
  }
}

new Child().logSomething();
```

You can call any function or use any property of the parent class using `this`, as long as the new class doesn't have its own definition for that property.

Comment: Very detailed, I like it, I have just one question left, how come in ```React``` you can do ```componentWillMount() { // after the component mounts it runs whatever is in here }```? It there some kind of special manipulation going on under the hook that allows for this?

Comment: @Nick09 I'm confused as to why that could be an issue.

Comment: Its not a issue, I was just wondering if there's any explanation for that, because everything tied to the ```JavaScript Class System``` seems to reflect in ```React```, everything but this and I was wondering why :)

Comment: I still don't understand, why you think `componentWillMount` should throw an error in React?

Comment: because you write it directly inside the body of the ```Child``` that ```extends Component``` like this ``` componentWillMount() { // after the component mounts it runs whatever is in here }``` as opposed to the method that you've just detailed for us, that needs to be called inside the ```constructor``` or from inside another function. With ```React``` and ```componentWillMount``` you don't do it inside the ```constructor```, you do it directly in the ```block scope``` of the class, so directly inside the ```class Child extends Parent { componentWillMount() { // code to execute } }```

Comment: @Nick09 In the last example isn't `logSomething` in the scope of the class? What's the difference?

Comment: in my mind, the difference was that the ```logSomething``` that is inside the ```block scope``` of the class if called from outside with ```new Child().logSomething();```. But now I understand,  ```React``` probably works the same way, you add the ```componentDidMount``` function, or whatever else, and then ```React``` probably checks the child components to see if they have any of those functions defined in them, and if they do, it runs them. So when you do ```componentDidMount() { // run code }``` is just does ```new Child().component()```. Is this right?

Answer (score 2):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854958/how-to-call-a-parent-method-from-child-class-in-javascript) for more information.

```
class Parent {
  constructor() {}

  logSomething() {
    console.log('I am logging something')
  }

}

class Child extends Parent {
  logSomething() {
    super.logSomething(); // Call parent function
  }

}
```

Comment: you can use `this.logSomething()` in a function in the child that isn't called `logSomething` :p

Comment: @JaromandaX That is incorrect, you need to not have a function or property called `logSomething`, to be able to use `Parent#logSomething` using `this.logSomething`

Comment: Yes, in my solution you override the parent function and call the parent function inside of the child function ;)

Comment: @nickzoum - you misunderstood my comment, but I forgive you

Answer (score 1):

a) you can't call a function there, you can call a function within a function declared in a class

b) you need to use this.logSomething()

example:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {}
  logSomething() {
    console.log('I am logging something')
  }

}

class Child extends Parent {
  fn() {
    this.logSomething() // This does work
  }
}
new Child().fn()
```

See other answers for when `fn` is called `logSomething` in the child class - then you'd need `super.logSomething()` to call the "parent" logSomething instead of the child logSomething