# Stuff about default function arguments

Tags: javascript

Uncaught ReferenceError: Must call super constructor in derived class before accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor

Did anyone have an idea about this error and where I can learn more about it?

Comment: the super constructor looks like this `super()`. you need to call it in the contructor of any inherited classes.

Comment: Have a look at: [Why isn't "this" allowed before super?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539654/why-isnt-this-allowed-before-super)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the super constructor, like the error says. Here's an example to illustrate:

```js
class Person{
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Batman extends Person{
  constructor(){
    super(); // <--- You need to do this.
    this.name = 'Batman';
  }
}

var batman = new Batman();
```