# How do bind subclass 'this' when calling an overridden method from the parent class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I created a `Drawable` (base) class and made every `Canvas` object implement this common API. The problem is that the `this` passed to the subclass does not have any properties of the subclass. How do I fix this?

I have extracted the problem and here's a simplified version of the same code.

```js
// File: parent.ts
export abstract class Parent {
  
    constructor(protected readonly parentProp: string) {
       if (autoSetup) this.setup();
    }

    setup(): void { /* no default setup required */ }
}
```

```js
// File: child.ts
import { Parent } from './parent.ts';

export class Child extends Parent {
    
    constructor(prop1: string, public prop2: string) {
        super(prop1);
    }

    override setup(): void {
        console.log(this.prop2);  // undefined, why?
        
        // do other things with prop2
    }
}
```

Now when the `Child` is instantiated, the `Parent` class constructor calls the setup and passes it its own `this`. How do I make that `this` include the sub class properties too?

Comment: Could you [edit] this code to remove the distractions that make the problem less obvious: the `autoSetup` parameter (it's just `true` here); and the [parameter properties](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties) which hide where the property assignments happen.  Your code is equivalent to [this version](https://tsplay.dev/m0VrRw), a [mre] where you can see exactly why `prop2` and `prop3` don't exist yet.  You'd like to somehow move those assignments before `super`, but that isn't allowed, so the question would be asking for alternatives.

Comment: In a parent/child class relationship, `this` is the exact same thing between the parent code and the child code; there's only one object.

Comment: @jcalz Hey! I have edited the code to make the problem clearer. Does that help? The problem I'm facing is why is `this.prop2` undefined? it should be initialised to whatever the constructor is passed. And yes as an alternative, how should I approach this problem then?

Comment: I suggested [this version](https://tsplay.dev/m0VrRw) to make the problem clearer.  Could you use that instead? If not, why not?

Comment: @jcalz Sure! In the [version of code](https://tsplay.dev/m0VrRw) that you provided, how would you achieve what I've described above?

Comment: I don't necessarily know, but maybe someone else familiar with JavaScript and not TypeScript would have some suggestions, if you [edit] the question to use that version.  This code makes it painfully obvious that `prop2` and `prop3` are not set before `setup()` is called, so the problem will be on display this way.  So far any approach I've come up with seems really clunky and not something I'd feel good about recommending.

Comment: this is one of the many reasons you should not call a "virtual" method from a constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately what you are trying to do isn't possible. The way class inheritance works in JS, is that the `this` object of the derived class isn't initialized until the `super()` call finishes running (see also [Why isn't `this` allowed before `super()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55807566)).

When you call `super()`, you call the constructor of the `Parent` class, which in turn calls the `setup()` method of the `Child` class. While `setup()` is running, `super()` still hasn't finished, which is why `this` still isn't initialized in the context of `Child`. Since at this point `this` was only initialized in the context of `Parent`, you can only access fields that were initialized by the `Parent`'s constructor (such as `this.parentProp`). This is why you cannot make it so that `this` will include the sub class properties when `setup()` is called.

Another point to pay attention to is how TypeScript's [Parameter Properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties) work. Essentially, it's just syntax sugar that is equivalent to declaring the fields and initializing them immediately after the `super()` call. This means that your code is equivalent to the following:

```js
export abstract class Parent {
    protected readonly parentProp: string;
    constructor(parentProp: string) {
        this.parentProp = parentProp;
        if (autoSetup) this.setup();
    }

    setup(): void { /* no default setup required */ }
}

export class Child extends Parent {
    public prop2: string;
    constructor(prop1: string, prop2: string) {
        super(prop1);
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }

    override setup(): void {
        console.log(this.prop2);
    }
}
```

As you can see, when `setup()` is called, `this.prop2` hasn't been defined yet, and so it is `undefined`.

---

Instead of the above, I suggest that you call `setup()` from within the `Child` class, after the `super()` call has finished, like so:

```js
export abstract class Parent {
    constructor(protected readonly parentProp: string) { }

    abstract setup(): void
}

export class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(prop1: string, public prop2: string) {
        super(prop1);
        if (autoSetup) this.setup();
    }

    override setup(): void {
        console.log(this.prop2);
    }
}

new Child('prop1', 'prop2') // Prints "prop2"
```

This way, `setup()` will run after `this` has been initialized in the context of `Child`, and so `this.prop2` will be defined correctly.

Alternatively, if you really need to call `setup()` from `Parent`, you can pass `prop2` as a parameter to the `Parent` constructor, although this looks worse in my opinion:

```js
export abstract class Parent {
    constructor(protected readonly parentProp: string, prop2: string) {
       if (autoSetup) this.setup(prop2);
    }

    abstract setup(prop2: string): void
}

export class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(prop1: string, public prop2: string) {
        super(prop1, prop2);
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }

    override setup(prop2: string): void {
        console.log(prop2);
    }
}

new Child('prop1', 'prop2') // Prints "prop2"
```